# Grep a Log file for the last occurrence of a string between two strings

Tags: unix, grep, tail

I have a log file `trace.log`. In it I need to grep for the content contained within the strings `<tag>` and `</tag>`. There are multiple sets of this pair of strings, and I just need to return the content between last set (in other words, from the `tail` of the log file).

Extra Credit: Any way I can return the content contained within the two strings only if the content contains "testString"?

Thanks for looking.

EDIT: The search parameters  and  are contained on different lines with about 100 lines of content separating them. The content is what I'm after...

Comment: Examples of input might help; it's not clear whether the tags are on same line or on different ones.

Comment: the tags are on different lines ..and we're looking at about 70-100 lines of content within the tags.

Comment: Rather than putting this information in the comments, update your question.  Apparently, the responses that you've received assume that the tags are on the same line.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Use `tac` to print the file the other way round and then `grep -m1` to just print one result. The look behind and look ahead checks text in between `<tag>` and `</tag>`.

```
tac a | grep -m1 -oP '(?<=tag>).*(?=</tag>)'
```

#### Test

Given this file

```
$ cat a
<tag> and </tag>
aaa <tag> and <b> other things </tag>
adsaad <tag>and  last one</tag>

$ tac a | grep -m1 -oP '(?<=tag>).*(?=</tag>)'
and  last one
```

---

## Update

> EDIT: The search parameters and are contained on different lines with
>   about 100 lines of content separating them. The content is what I'm
>   after...

Then it is a bit more tricky:

```
tac file | awk '/<\/tag>/ {p=1; split($0, a, "</tag>"); $0=a[1]};
                /<tag>/   {p=0; split($0, a, "<tag>");  $0=a[2]; print; exit};
                p' | tac
```

The idea is to reverse the file and use a flag `p` to check if the `<tag>` has appeared yet or not. It will start printing when `</tag>` appears and finished when `<tag>` comes (because we are reading the other way round).

- `split($0, a, "</tag>"); $0=a[1];` gets the data before `</tag>`
- `split($0, a, "<tag>" ); $0=a[2];` gets the data after `<tag>`

#### Test

Given a file `a` like this:

```
<tag> and </tag>
aaa <tag> and <b> other thing
come here
and here </tag>

some text<tag>tag is starting here
blabla
and ends here</tag>
```

The output will be:

```
$ tac a | awk '/<\/tag>/ {p=1; split($0, a, "</tag>"); $0=a[1]}; /<tag>/ {p=0; split($0, a, "<tag>"); $0=a[2]; print; exit}; p' | tac
tag is starting here
blabla
and ends here
```

Answer (score 26):

If like me, you don't have access to tac because your sysadmin won't play ball you can try:

```
grep pattern file | tail -1
```

Comment: Thanks, this should be right answer. because tac will mess with linenumbers in output, tail -1 did the trick

Comment: also- tac- not standard on all systems

Comment: Note, however, that this does not take into account the _between two strings_ part.

Answer (score 1):

Another solution than grep would be sed:

```
tac file | sed -n '0,/<tag>\(.*\)<\/tag>/s//\1/p'
```

`tac file` prints the file in the reverse order (`cat` backwards), then `sed` proceeds from input line `0` to the first occurence of `<tag>.*<\tag>`, and substitutes `<tag>.*<\tag>` with only the part that was inside `<tag>`. The `p` flag prints the output, which was suppressed by `-n`.

Edit: This does not work if `<tag>` and `</tag>` are on different lines. We can still use `sed` for that:

```
tac file | sed -n '/<\/tag>/,$p; /<tag>/q' | sed 's/.*<tag>//; s/<\/tag>.*//' | tac
```

Again we use `tac` to read the file backwards, then the first `sed` command reads from the first occurrence of  and quits when it finds . Only the lines in between are printed. Then we pass it to another `sed` process to strip the 's and finally reverse the lines again with `tac`.

Answer (score 0):

```
perl -e '$/=undef; $f=<>; push @a,$1 while($f=~m#<tag>(.*?)</tag>#msg); print $a[-1]' ex.txt
```

> Extra Credit: Any way I can return the content contained within the
>   two strings only if the content contains "testString"?

```
perl -e '$/=undef; $f=<>; push @a,$1 while($f=~m#<tag>(.*?)</tag>#msg); print $a[-1] if ($a[-1]~=/teststring/);' ex.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

A little *untested* awk that handles multiple lines:

```
awk '
    BEGIN    {retain="false"}
    /<\tag>/ {retain = retain + $0; keep="false"; next}
    /<tag>/  {keep = "true"; retain = $0; next}
    keep == "true" {retain = retain + $0}
    END {print retain}
' filename
```

We start just reading the file; when we hit the , we start keeping lines. When we hit the , we stop. If we hit another , we clear the retained string and start again. If you want all the  strings, print at each